# python bs4.element.Tag get dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I get the nested "props" as a dictionary?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20201103&end=20201104').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
foo = soup.find('script', id="__NEXT_DATA__", type='application/json')
print ((foo))
```

Comment: use `data = json.loads(foo.contents[0])`
`print(data)`

Comment: Solved. Thank your for the prompt reply @eyllanesc